# How to use the browser history api to invoke a function when back & forward buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript, browser-history, history.js

Let's say I have a page: http://www.example.com/foo.htm

I would like to place a button which shows one portion of the page and hides the other, such as:

HTML-

```
<p class="stepOne">Hi, I'm step one. <a id="doit" href="#">Go to Step 2</a></p>
<p class="stepTwo">And I'm step two</p>
```

JS-

```
$('#doit').on('click', function(){
    $('.stepOne').hide();
    $('.stepTwo').show();
});
```

My question is:
After the user clicks the "Go to Step 2" link, how can I use the HTML history api to hide step two and show step one when the user clicks the browser's back button?

Comment: This is typically done through the popstate event, however keep browser support in mind when doing anything with the history api. I tend to instead use a library rather than build this myself, as it is pretty involved if you want compatibility with common but not so modern browsers.

Comment: Using some tricky css you can actually do it without javascript at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Ps4XW/ :) For modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of the browser's history as a stack. Each time you click a link or navigate forward, you push items onto the stack. Whenever you want to go backward, the browser "pops" an item off of the stack. Let's call each of these items a "state". The browser keeps a few pieces of information about each state, like the URL, title, and a "state object" if needed. In summary, new states get pushed on to the stack when you go forward and the most recent state gets popped off of the end when you want to go backwards.

With that in mind, what you want to accomplish is pushing a state onto the stack manually. In this way, the user isn't actually navigating anywhere—the HTML5 History API gives us the ability to push/pop/replace the states in the browser's history stack without the page changing.

In your `click` event listener, you'll need to add some code to add a new state to the history stack. Something like: `window.history.pushState({}, 'Step 2', '/step-2');`

This will add a new state to the history stack and your URL will change to `/step-2`. Now when you click the back button, it will `pop` this state off of the stack and go back to the previous state. Both states are the same page and DOM.

Now you have to account for changing the visibility of those two items on the page when the user navigates `back` in their browser. This can be detected via a `popstate` event that gets fired on the `window` every time the state changes. Check out [this plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zNMZFLNFqHPnYYRYugJ?p=preview) I put together. In the click event listener, the DOM is changed (hiding and showing the items) and a new history state is pushed onto the stack with an integer representing what step should be shown in that history state. Then, on a `popstate` event, the user is navigating backwards and in the event object, we're given the state that is being popped off. We know that we should be going backwards, so if the step that's being popped off is step 2, we'll want to show step 1.

I made some minor changes to the html to be able to write the code concisely and there's lots of room for modularity here—no need to hard-code step numbers in the javascript.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The following code responds to solve the problem you laid out in your question. Using the [HTML5 History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) we extend your example code like this (comments descriping the three parts A,B,C that have been added to your code)

```
// Part A: For the initial "step 1" we create a history state object
var historyStateObjectStep1 = {"step":"one"};
// which we tell the browser to use to represent the current state/step in
// history. Since the browser had an idea about the "now"-state in history 
// already, which is now "replaced" this is done via history.replaceState
history.replaceState(historyStateObjectStep1,"");

// Part B: To react to history events like back-/forward-button pressed, 
// we have to setup an EventListener for the "history"-popstate event. 
window.addEventListener("popstate",function(event){
      // the history state objects we have setup via replaceState/pushState
      // before are provided via the event objects property event.state
      var historyStateObject = event.state;

      // if state object is "object" and as setup has an attribute "step" 
      // with value "one"
      if(typeof historyStateObject == "object" 
         && historyStateObject.step === "one" )
      {
          // then it means that the user used the browsers "back" button 
          // and since we are now at history state "stepOne" we show it
          $('.stepOne').show();
          // and hide stepTwo
          $('.stepTwo').hide();
      } 
      // in else case that the historyStateObject is an object and has an
      // attribute step set to the value "two" then...
      else if(typeof historyStateObject == "object" 
         && historyStateObject.step === "two" )
      {
          //...the user has used the browser buttons (forward/back) to reach
          // the state "stepTwo", hence we show it and 
          $('.stepTwo').show();
          // hide stepOne
          $('.stepOne').hide();
      }
},false);


$('#doit').on('click', function(){
    // PART C: Upon clicking the "doit"-button (to go to step two), we 
    // create an history state object for step 2 
    var historyStateObjectStep2 = {"step":"two"};

    // which we then insert intto the browser history, or in other words 
    // "push" the newly created historyStateObejectStep2 to the history, via
    // the function history.pushState
    history.pushState(historyStateObjectStep2,"");


    $('.stepOne').hide();
    $('.stepTwo').show();
});
```